# ListView with PHP and Flutter

Tags: php, mysql, json, flutter

I'm studing flutter, I'm having fun to develop but I have a small difficulty..

As I am studying to display a catalog list via code Flutter LISTVIEW with JSON, PHP and MYSQL

And really I did so much research and I could not solve

PHP AND MYSQL

```
<?php

$queryCheck = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ORDER BY date ASC";
$selectCheck = mysqli_query($connessione, $queryCheck);
    
$numCheck = mysqli_num_rows($selectCheck);
    
if($numCheck > 0)
{

    $result = array();

    while($resultCheck = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCheck))
    {
    
        $events = array_push($result, array("id"=>$resultCheck['id'], "titolo"=>$resultCheck['titolo'], "codice_evento"=>$resultCheck['codice_evento'], "foto"=>$resultCheck['foto']));
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode($result);
    
}


?>
```

Testing on browser is code with correct JSON

```
[
{"id":"479","title":"titolo 1","code":"208736599514","pictures":"58027868511.jpg"},
{"id":"480","title":"titolo 2","code":"208736599514","pictures":"58027868511.jpg"},
{"id":"481","title":"titolo 3","code":"208736599514","pictures":"58027868511.jpg"},
{"id":"482","title":"titolo 4","code":"208736599514","pictures":"58027868511.jpg"}
]
```

FLUTTER WIDGET

```
late List dataEventiHome = [];

  initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getData() async {
    var url = "http://localhost/home.php";
    var responseEventiHome = await http.post(Uri.parse(url));
    dataHome = jsonDecode(responseEventiHome.body);
    setState((){});
    print(dataHome);
  }

Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
              child: Container(
                height: 250,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: dataHome.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){},
                          child: Container(
                            height: 190,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                color: Colors.green),
                            child: Image.network("http://localhost/"+ dataHome[index]['pictures'],fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                            child: Text(dataHome[index]['title'], style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "NovareseStd", color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          )
                      ),
                    );
```

On TERMINAL is shown the code JSON but on WIDGET LISTVIEW don't shown pictures or title, why?
What did I do wrong or what is missing?

Don't shown date from php and mysql on LISTVIEW

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you use localhost in your flutter code, you are referring to your mobile device (physical or emulator), not your computer, where your php server is running and your images are hosted.

You need to make your php server available to your device.

Comment: Look, I also tried on my server and it still doesn't work :(

The problem is that I have find on google and youtube, there are many but the variables are more or less the same but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.

I also tried using this code
print(dataHome.length);

Is work and shown the risult on terminal FLUTTER: 14